# Does manual firmware update needs boot loader unlocked?

Tags: bootloader, device-firmware

I tried manually update my phones firmware but I didn't get any notification after I put zip file to root directory of internal storage.
So does it need boot loader unlocked?

Comment: Depends upon what you mean manual here? Which phone and Android version is it? If you are trying to flash using fastboot or a similar low-level environment, bootloader needs to be unlocked. Since firmware updates are official usually, they can be flashed using stock recovery but without unlocking bootloader. Although, you might be talking about inbuilt system updater option in Settings app.

Comment: Manual means official firmware updates but not with inbuilt system updater just download zip from official website that's manual.